# How to prove indirectly that there exist no positive integers $x$ and $y$ for which $x^2 - y^2 = 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I already did it with a contraposition. But how to do it indirectly? It has to be something like "there exist positive integers $x$ and $y$ for wich $x^2 - y^2  = 1$".

Tried to use $(x+y)(x-y)=1$ and follow that $x-y=1$ and $x+y=1$ so that $y=-y$, which cannot be true with positive integers. Possible?

Comment: Or notice that $x+y\ge 2$ and $x-y\ge 1$, so $(x+y)(x-y)\ge 2$.

Comment: Technically, you should check the case where both are $-1$ also, but that is still impossible for positive integers, so yes. I would say your proof works.

Comment: The difference of two squares of distinct positive integers, is always of the form $2nh+h^2$ for n, h natural numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Since the difference of two consecutive squares is:
$$(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1,$$
and $2n+1=1\implies n=0$, the result follows.

Comment: Why do you assume they are consecutive?

Comment: I see what you're saying though.

Comment: Well if the difference of two squares is $1$, the two squares would have to be as close as possible.

Comment: Or in other words, $(n+i)^2-n^2$ is an increasing function for all i>0

Comment: @MatthewLevy Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$(n+i)^2-n^2=2in+i^2$$

So, for any $n>0$ we have an increasing function of $i$, and vice versa. If $i\geq 1$ then $$(n+i)^2-n^2\geq 2n+1\implies n\leq0$$

But, we are looking for positive numbers $n$.
Also, it may be obvious but if $x<y$ then there is no way for $x^2-y^2=1$.

Another way of looking at it would be 
$$\forall n,i\in\mathbb N \;2in+i^2\geq 3$$

Comment: Even though it's specified we are talking about integers I would never call a variable $i$ because it usually means the imaginary number.